# Referencing completion handler function in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, function, completionhandler

I am using the `CBStorePullToRefresh` feature which is working all good. I have now added a completion to one of the functions so I can wait until the function is complete and then reload table data.

Used to look like this but `reloadData` was being called to early since `getEventInfo` finds object in background with Parse.

```
func reloadDataFromServer() {
   getEventInfo()
   self.tableview.reloadData
 }
```

Now looks like this, I then call the `reloadData` in the completion -

```
func reloadDataFromServer(completionHandler: (() -> Void)!) {
   getEventInfo()
  completionHandler()
}
```

I can't seem to reference it in in refreshAction when setting up here -

```
refreshControl = CBStoreHouseRefreshControl.attachToScrollView(tableView, target: self, refreshAction: "reloadDataFromServer", plist: "PullToRefreshAnimation", color: UIColor.whiteColor(), lineWidth: 1.5, dropHeight: 80, scale: 2, horizontalRandomness: 150, reverseLoadingAnimation: true, internalAnimationFactor: 0.5)
```

I have tried many ways, things like `reloadDataFromServer(completionHandler)` but it don't seem to pick it up. What am I missing here??

Comment: You need to pass `completionHandler` to `getEventInfo` so that you can call it from the completion block on the Parse call

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention I am also calling self.refreshControl?.finishingLoading() after reloading table data. So isn't ideal calling it in side the main getEventInfo func as you only want it to refreshControl when pulled to refresh. That being said its an optional so it dose work only when the refresh control is on. So putting it in their works perfect but is this the cleanest way to do it, whats your opinion Paul? Thanks mate

Comment: If you pass the completion handler into `getEventInfo` then it can call the completion handler, but the closure is defined by the code that is calling `reloadDataFromServer` - this means that your `getEventInfo` is completely decoupled from your view controller and doesn't need to know anything about refresh controls or even that it needs to reload the table view.